# Finding birthparents for 1957 Florida adoptee?

Tags: united-states, adoption, 1950s, florida

My mother was adopted but i have no information to find her birth parents, what should i do to find them?

She was born in 1957 in Florida that's all I know. I do not know any other details except the names of the people who adopted her.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Here you are referring to people who were probably born less than 100 years ago, so we are redacting their names.  See our Privacy Policy in the [help] for ways you may be able to keep those details displayed.

Comment: If you are not willing to take the privacy risks of giving your DNA to Ancestry I'm sure there will be paperwork about the adoption somewhere. Don't have any specifics hence only a comment.

Comment: @nebulon42 Interested to know what you think are the privacy risks -- we could talk about it in chat perhaps: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6003/roots

Comment: Hi Jennifer, it's not clear from your question whether your mother is still living. That will affect how you approach this.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic application of DNA testing. Have your mother take an atDNA test at Ancestry (which will allow to to transfer her results to many other sites) and prepare to put in some hard work analysing her matches to track down her birth family.

I'm suggesting Ancestry because they allow DNA data to be exported for import to other sites (which widens the pool of potential matches) but they don't allow imports; so starting at Ancestry gives you the widest possible set of matches.

There are Facebook groups that specialise in helping adoptees looking for their birth families, such as [DNA Detectives](https://www.facebook.com/groups/DNADetectives/). It's worth joining to try and find somebody who will guide you through the process.